# Making a logic circuit with only NAND GATES?

Tags: logic-gates, nand, not-gate

[image]I am trying to create a logic circuit using only NAND Gates for this expression:
(NOT Q AND P) OR R

This question has really gotten me stuck! Can somebody please help?

Comment: Have you learned DeMorgan's laws yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes i have - i have done other expressions but this one has really gotten me confused and im not sure why - i have added a picture of what i have done so far

Comment: Why are you drawing anything? Get the equation first.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - I got the first bit but i thought if i draw something i should be able to understand the rest - im unsure on how to convert OR R to the nand bit

Comment: That's what DeMorgan's laws are for.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes i know, i have tried it and cannot get anywhere which is why i put this here to get help

Comment: "Denial of DeMorgan"?

Comment: the logic NAND gate is generally classed as a "UNIVERSAL"gate because it is one of the most commonly used logic gate type.
there are three basic gate types of AND,OR and NOT formed using only NAND'S.
for example

Comment: Your picture doesn't seem to match your word description at all.

Answer (score 24):

The best way for a beginner is to think about each term separately and how you would create that with a NAND gate.

Let's start with the basic NAND gate truth table:

```
A | B | Q
---------
0 | 0 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

Now let's look at each term.  We have a NOT, and AND, and an OR in there.  So, how can we make those with NAND gates?  Start with the NOT.

How does a NAND look like a NOT? Simple - when both inputs are the same. If you tie A and B together so they always see the same signal, then you have a NOT gate.  0 nand 0 = 1, 1 nand 1 = 0.  So the NOT gate can just be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpzYom.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Next the AND.  What's a NAND? It's an inverted AND.  And AND with a NOT after it.  So we just want to get rid of the NOT, and you can do that by adding another NOT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1LSuz.png)</sup>

Then comes the OR.  Look closely at the NAND table and compare it to the OR table:

```
A | B | Q
---------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

Do you see a similarity?  If you were to invert the A and B values the table would instead look like this:

```
A | B | Q
---------
1 | 1 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 0 | 0
```

And that's the same sequence for Q as the NAND gate.  So an OR gate is just a NAND gate with the inputs inverted.  And we know how to invert already.  So the OR looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmUpW0.png)</sup>

So now you know what the gates look like you can put the whole thing together:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgi8j2.png)</sup>

However there's too many gates there. It can be simplified.  The bit I have marked with a box - a NOT followed by a NOT - that's completely pointless (from a logic point of view) and is just wasteful.  It serves no purpose.  So you can get rid of it.  Simplify to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxEyJk.png)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

\$(\overline Q P) + R\$

\$=\overline{(\overline {\overline Q P}) \overline R}\$

= (NOT Q NAND P) NAND NOT R

Comment: Care to provide a short follow up narative?